# How to check if Rewarded Ads are available?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console, admob, ads

I need to check If the rewarded video is Loaded or not, so I have this function :

```
private bool IsAdAvailable()
{
    if (AdmobController.instance.rewardBasedVideo == null) return false;

    bool isLoaded = AdmobController.instance.rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded();

    if (!isLoaded)
    {
        AdmobController.instance.RequestRewardBasedVideo();
    }

    return isLoaded;
}
```

This is RequestRewardBasedVideo function :

```
         public void RequestRewardBasedVideo()
         {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
               string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
               string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313";
#else
               string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

              // Create an empty ad request.
              AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
             // Load the rewarded video ad with the request.
              this.rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
         }
```

and this is the function that shows the rewarded video If it Loaded, If not It will show that message to user.

```
public void ShowRewardedAds()
{
    if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
    {
        rewardBasedVideo.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("Reward based video ad is not ready yet");
    }

}
```

But when I run my program in unity, In the console this message keep showing with no stop :

```
Dummy IsLoaded
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

It's like the program keep checking if the reward video is loaded or not.

I have tried to delete all the statements in `IsAdAvailable()` except `return isLoaded` I replaced it with `return true`.

and the message stopped showing with no stop, It showed just one time.
and that's what I want.

So is there a better way to check If the reward video is loaded or not ?

If you need more information about my code feel free to ask.

this is my Admob controller script :
https://pastebin.com/TNNPKxQF

this is the rewarded video button script :
https://pastebin.com/FipHV9wt

this is the Rewarded Video CallBack script :
https://pastebin.com/g65zjBwt

[image]
[image]
[image]

***#edit***

I deleted all the statements from `IsAdAvailable()` exept
 `AdmobController.instance.RequestRewardBasedVideo();`
and `return true`
and I run my program and the problem still exist, the message Dummy IsLoaded keep showing with no stop.
so I think the problem from this statement `AdmobController.instance.RequestRewardBasedVideo();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read how to implement rewarded video ads in the [Google AdMob Mobile Ads SDK (Unity)
documentation.](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded-video)

The best way to check if the reward video is loaded is by hooking into RewardBasedVideoAd `OnAdLoaded` event:

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
...
public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo;
    ...

    public void Start()
    {
        // Get singleton reward based video ad reference.
        this.rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

        // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
        // Called when an ad request failed to load.
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;

        this.RequestRewardBasedVideo();
    }

    private void RequestRewardBasedVideo()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313";
        #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the rewarded video ad with the request.
        this.rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print(
            "HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad event received with message: "
                             + args.Message);
    }
```

You should also use events to check if the ad was shown, closed, clicked etc.

Comment: Yes this exactly what I am doing you can check my script here                 https://pastebin.com/FipHV9wt           this is the rewardedButton script

Comment: I have noticed that this function is the responsible of calling IsAdAvalible() so many times.              
 private void IUpdate()
    {
        SetActive(IsAvailableToShow());
    }    
It's not my code but I need to understand it, and fix it.

Comment: In the start method you are using the InvokeRepeating function that will call the IUpdate method every second

Comment: I'll check it,and I'll inform you if there is something new.

Comment: Yes that was the problem I deleted the invoke method and update function, and now it works perfectly.

Comment: but still I have some problems with the time counter, but thanks for your efforts.

Comment: No problem, if you have other problems you cant solve I suggest you start a new question.